# issues with WS2_32.dll behavior between windows 10 vs windows7

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, log4cxx

Did not find any suitable solution with existing questions so asking new question here.
We use log4cxx which has WS2_32.LIB as dependency. WS2_32.LIB is present in Windows SDK version 10.0.16299.0.
When using this log4cxx.dll on windows7 WS2_32.dll and all its dependencies gets loaded properly and application start normally.

but in windows 10 environment WS2_32.dll expects dependent dll's like API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L1-1-0.DLL which are not part of windows10 or any of the microsoft visual c++ Redistributable which results in application error.

difference in WS2_32.dll and its dependencies between Windows7 and windows10 are clearly visible via dependency walker.

WS2_32.dll on windows 10:
[image]

whereas
WS2_32.dll on windows7 is
[image]

as shown here API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L1-1-0.DLL is not a dependent dll in windows7 where as its in windows 10 which is not present in the system resulting in application error.

So what should be the way to make the application run successfully? what alternate dependency should be provided instead of WS2_32.LIB while compiling log4cxx.dll to avoid this issue in windows 10? Also where to find documentation about such changes between windows OS versions? 
Please suggest.

Comment: is question answered that the old depends.exe shows wrong data?

Comment: I've voted now to close the question as "unclear what is asked" because I still don't know what your issue is if my reply doesn't answer it

Comment: hey really sorry, i couldnt reply due to some personal issues. your new dependency walker pointing as api-ms-win-core-crt-l1-1-0.dll -> C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll which does not give clear picture and my application still fails while searching for this dll which is not present in the system

Answer (score 1):

The old depends.exe doesn't support those [API sets](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/apisetschema/api/index.htm?tx=2) and shows wrong data.

use the open source replacement called [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies/releases):

> Dependencies is a rewrite of the legacy software Dependency Walker
>   which was shipped along Windows SDKs, but whose developement stopped
>   around 2006. Dependencies can help Windows developers troubleshooting
>   their dll load dependencies issues.

[image]

Comment: hey thank you for your reply. but this does not solve my problem, my question is still valid. 
what should be the way to make the application run successfully? 
what alternate dependency if any should be provided instead of WS2_32.LIB while compiling log4cxx.dll to avoid this issue in windows 10?

Comment: post the error message of your program, I still don't see what your issue is

Comment: while loading the dll in the program it fails as in windows 10 environment it is unable to find the API-MS-WIN-CORE-CRT-L1-1-0.DLL. same program works in windows 7 as it does not look for this dll there.