# How to debug a Windows kernel driver properly?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, debugging, kernel

I'm trying to set up the environment of *Windows* VM for debugging a kernel driver.

I created a sample of kernel driver in Visual Studio 2017. **File->New Project->Kernel Mode Driver** (*basic project*; just for testing - autogenerated trace macro, required procedures, etc.) and want to test it on the *target machine*.

There are my steps (*target machine*):

1. Install Windows 10 to a virtual machine (VirtualBox);
2. [Turn on Test mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/the-testsigning-boot-configuration-option) and set [BCDEdit as local](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--dbgsettings);
3. Install [WDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk);
4. Download [OSR Loader](https://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=157);
5. Copy files after a building to a VM (C:\DriverTest\TestKernelDriver2\; **.cer**, **.inf**, **.pdb**, **.sys**);
6. Create **traces** folder; C:\DriverTest\TestKernelDriver2\traces\
7. Install the cerificate - **TestKernelDriver2.sys**; (*Sign mode*: **Test Sign**)
8. Run **OSR Driver Loader**, choose the driver, press **Register service** (*Success*).
9. Run [tracelog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/tracelog) with params (GUID was generated by templates; no via **Tools->Create GUID**) - *success*:

   `tracelog -start TestKernelDriver2 -guid #0f4fbb98-1569-495b-88d1-f654b1e2d68e -f C:\DriverTest\TestKernelDriver2\traces\trace.etl -flag 2 -level 0xFFFF`
10. Check C:\DriverTest\TestKernelDriver2\traces\trace.etl; (exist - **64KB** size)
11. OSR Driver Loader: press **Start Service** (*fail*). Error message: **The specified procedure could not be found.**
12. Stop **tracelog** - *success*:

    `tracelog -stop TestKernelDriver2`
13. Open [Event Viewer](https://www.howtogeek.com/123646/htg-explains-what-the-windows-event-viewer-is-and-how-you-can-use-it/). **Windows logs->System**. The last error:

    `The TestKernelDriver2 service failed to start due to the following error: 
    The specified procedure could not be found.`

    `Details:
         EventData 
         param1 TestKernelDriver2 
         param2 %%127 
       54006500730074004B00650072006E0065006C0044007200690076006500720032000000`
14. Open C:\DriverTest\TestKernelDriver2\traces\trace.etl via **Event Viewer** and don't see any logs.

How can I find out what is procedure was missed?

I tried to investigate it via [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and revealed that some **.sys** files are missed (**WppRecorder.sys**, **WdfLdr.sys**, **msrpc.sys**, **EXT-MS-WIN-**###**.DLL**). These filed are located in C:\Windows\System32\drivers. I copied the files to C:\Windows\System32 and **Dependency Walker** calmed down. What about EXT-MS-WIN-*.DLL - I read in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40077240/4359175) that these files can be missed.

Thanks to @magicandre1981. I installed my driver via [PnPUtil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-examples). But now, I see it in the list of **pnputil /enum-drivers** command.

[image]

But when I run the following commands in **WinDbg**, I don't see my driver in the list:

```
!load wdfkd.dll
!wdfkd.wdfldr
```

[image]

I'm trying to make steps of Session 1 from [this Microsoft ttutoriall](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/wdf/debugging-kernel-mode-driver-framework-drivers).

Comment: use [this new tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54256372/1466046) it supports the API sets

Comment: Thank you so much - this is a really useful tool. I see which **.sys** files are missed, but I can't realize the next thing. I see these missing files in **C:\Windows\System32\drivers**, but Windows tries to search these in **C:\Windows\System32**. Maybe do you know why is this happening? Copying files from **..\drivers** to **System32** folder is an awful idea. This need not be so.

Comment: this is expected . install the driver each time with devcon.exe which places the sys in system32/drivers.

Comment: Why can't I use **OSR Loader**? As I understand, I need to force **OSR Loader** search **.sys** files in **C:\Windows\System32\drivers**.

Comment: I haven't used this tool before. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debug-universal-drivers--kernel-mode-#install

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I handled with installing via PnPUtil. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/pnputil-examples

Comment: ok and now everything works and you can debug the driver?

Comment: If be honest - no. I can't see any trace in WinDbg. But your comments helped me to resolve the problem with installing. If you know what is the reason for the empty log traces I will be glad to know. I restart PC with disabling Driver signature, run WinDbg for local kernel debugging, wait to connect and after that install driver. Debugging console doesn't change. Traces in the driver via macro *TraceEvents(...)*.

Comment: So, it seems the driver wasn't installed. I ran in WinDbg: **!wdfkd.wdfldr** and didn't see my driver on the list. However, via **pnputil /enum-drivers** I see it.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution via [tracefmt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/example-9--creating-a-tmf-file) generator and [TraceView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/creating-a-trace-session-with-a-control-guid) application.

**Step 0**: Generate tmf file by command:

```
tracefmt С:\TestDriver\TestKernelDriver2\TestKernelDriver2.etl -i С:\TestDriver\TestKernelDriver2\TestKernelDriver2.sys -r С:\TestDriver\TestKernelDriver2\TestKernelDriver2 -p С:\TestDriver\TestKernelDriver2\tmfs -o С:\TestDriver\TestKernelDriver2\TestKernelDriver2.txt -v
```

**Step 1**: Create Session in TraceView:
**File** -> **Create New Session**. Fill **Manually Entered Control GUID**. (*0f4fbb98-1569-495b-88d1-f654b1e2d68e*)

**Step 2**: **Choose Source of WPP Format Information** (**Set TMF Search Path** option) and fill path: *C:\DriverTest\TestKernelDriver2\tmfs*

**Step 3**: *Next*, fill **Log Session Name** and **Real-Time Display** is checked. *Finish*.

[image: TraceView settings]

Comment: Ooopppss. For generating tmf files should be used the following command: **tracepdb.exe -f TestKernelDriver2\TestKernelDriver2.pdb -p TestKernelDriver2\tmfs**